# NODE.JS: Why can't I get live reload with web pack?

Tags: node.js, livereload

IM SO FRUSTRATED RIGHT NOW, ive spent a whole day trying to get webpack to work, but every tutorial or documentation is terrible..it shouldnt be this hard..whats the point of these packages if they actually make you spend more time trying to configure them then saving time.

I just want the live reload to work. I've tried the inline method, iframe, hot module, the middleware with express. None of it works...Im using Node.js on atom, with safari browser.

I want it to work with express.

Can someone point me to a good tutorial...or explain step by step very simply..

Need help. please. no one every replies on these things! Thank you

[GITHUB REPO LINK](http://github.com/koz24/C8B)

webpack.config.js

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports =
{
  entry: './app.js',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8000,
    open: true,
    inline: true
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "clinic8beauty",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "b": "webpack",
    "s": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
  "author": "Kosta Pontidas",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "twilio": "^2.11.1",
    "validator": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "pug-html-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.5.4"
  }
}
```

app.js requires

```
const express = require('express'),
      app = express(),
      events = require('events'),
      eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter(),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      validator = require('validator'),
      client = require('twilio')('AC3cdbdc7ecb720d5521f41243450343e8',
                             '8f76c52d839dc25aa17ddc72b3b9d781');
```

Comment: Pointing to tutorials is off-topic on SO. However, if you post your code and tell us what isn't working, then we could offer some help.

Comment: Where's your config file?

Comment: give me a second ill upload now

Comment: just create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: uploaded the config file above @dummy

Comment: Add this to your `devServer` `contentBase: [__dirname, __dirname + "/dist"]`

Comment: doesn't fix the problem @Dummy

Comment: @koz how are you running your app, please share more code like version of     dev-server, version of webpack or the whole package.json

Comment: package.json dependancies above @MrJSingh

Answer (score 0):

You have target node in your config change it to web or remove it as default is web. It should fix your problem.

Comment: are you running your app by using webpack-dev-server? can u share your package.json

Comment: please share the whole package.json including script part.

Comment: try to replase s script with this "s":"webpack-dev-server --progress --hot  --bail"

and see if you get any errors.

Comment: can you try to removeexternals: [nodeExternals()], and replace devServer with devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142439/discussion-between-mrjsingh-and-koz).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const path = require('webpack'); // <== added

module.exports =
{
  entry: './app.js',
 // target: 'node', <== deleted
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), //<== added
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8000,
    open: true,
    inline: true,
    contentBase: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')/* add other directories if needed */]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And run `webpack-dev-server --progress` instead of just `webpack` to start the server

Comment: under the views folder @Dummy

Comment: i did... @Dummy

Comment: I added "path.resolve(__dirname, 'views')" to the array

Comment: I did that... @Dummy

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: ohhh the terminal reloaded automatically

Comment: here's my github repo --->>>
[GITHUB REPO](http://github.com/koz24/C8B)

Comment: Try updating the `script` line in your index file to `<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/app.bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: Im getting : "app.bundle.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" in the browser console... i wasnt getting that before

Comment: Can you check to see if `dist` is a sibling to `views` folder?

Comment: No, it is probably ignored, that's just weird that it can't find `app.bundle.js` since `..dist/app.bundle.js` should resolve to it inside `views/index.html`

Comment: only literally just started doing that...but even when it was finding the file before, it came up with another error saying "
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require"

Comment: Try using `import` instead of `require`, e.g `import { foo } from "bar";` at the top of the page

Comment: can you give me an example with my specific file

Comment: Post your `require`

Comment: ill post it above

Comment: in the documentation, it says for it to work with node.js API,  I have to add the following to all entry points: webpack-dev-server/client?http://«path»:«port»/...[DOCUMENTATION](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)

Comment: Oh. You are writing a nodejs backend. Even though I am not familiar with nodejs, I don't think you can achieve live reload for server side code, I mean it doesn't make sense to live reload server side code. Live reloading is for frontend code. Also, that website is for the old version of webpack, here is the new one https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/

Comment: but I want to edit the css and html files and it to reload after that, so isnt that front end?

Comment: Then you have to add their containing directory to `contentBase` too

Comment: the documentation is saying to create a new Webpack dev server, looks straight forward, but how would I blend it with express??

Comment: 1. https://github.com/christianalfoni/webpack-express-boilerplate. 2. https://runkit.com/npm/webpack-express-middleware these seem promising

Answer (score 0):

Why not use nodemon globally and webpack to compile